# Can we use 'Apex Wire Method to Function' type more than once in js file?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

When I am using two **apex Wire Method to Function** type, only one wire method is responsive. I am not sure if I am doing it right. Please can anyone help?

```
@wire(totalApplication) 
  wireRecord({ error, data }) {

    if(data){
      this.totalSubcontractApp = data;
      this.error = undefined;
      }else if (error){
      this.error = error;
      this.totalSubcontractApp = undefined;
    }
    };
```

AND

```
@wire(partialSubcontractRecord)
 wireRecord({ error, data }) {
     this.paginationList = data;
     this.error = undefined;
    }else if(error){
      this.error = error;
      this.paginationList= undefined;
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick different name for your handler function. The "magic" is in `@wire`, not in `wireRecord` name.

Let's ignore custom handlers of result in JavaScript, forget the whole `({error, data})` and everything after it. Back to basics, to saving result in a variable. Like `@wire(getContactList) contacts;` in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex. You wouldn't have 2 methods writing stuff to same variable name and complain only 1 result at a time "works", right?

Call them

```
@wire(totalApplication) wiredTotalApplication({ error, data }) {...
@wire(partialSubcontractRecord) wiredPartialSubcontractRecord({ error, data }) {...
```

Comment: Thank you @eyescream